# Why is await operator giving error wcalling a method marked async metho

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I know similar questions have been asked, but I am at a loss on this one.  I get the message:

CS4032  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

with the following line of code:

```
var something = await _service.GetCurrentSomething(userAuthenticated);
```

and here is the method, clearly marked async (it is calling an API):

```
public async Task<Something> GetCurrentSomething(bool isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        var response = _httpClientWrapper.ExecuteGet(
            _insert params here
        ).Result;

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Announcement>(response.ResponseBody);
        return result;
    }
```

Now the compiler is not complaining about this method signature at all.  So why the error message?  I am calling it from inside an MVC controller, but I am not trying to return the "something" variable from the method.  So why the blurb about:

```
changing its return type to 'Task<ActionResult>'
```

By the way, I have done my research and nothing quite fits the bill.  The method is not a constructor, for example.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        var healthCheck = _heartbeatService.GetHeartBeat();

        if (healthCheck == null || healthCheck.Result == null || (!healtCheck.Result.Success))
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

        bool userAuthenticated = (user != null) && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (userAuthenticated)
        {
            var announcement = await _announcementService.GetCurrentAnnouncement(userAuthenticated);

            var model = CreateAnnouncementViewModel(announcement);

            if (user.IsInRole(Roles.WebAdmin) || user.IsInRole(Roles.Maintenance))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminGuy");
            }
            if (user.IsInRole(Roles.Shop))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shopguy");
            }
        }

        var viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        return View("HomePage", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: missed the last part of the error message in the beginning of the post.  see bottom please, it's asking for Task<ActionResult> in the MVC controller

Comment: "The method is not a constructor, for example." - but it's not an async method, by the sounds of it. The only reason that a constructor is often called out is that it *can't* be made asynchronous.

Comment: Multitasking via Async/Await requires a massive code rework by the compiler. You need to allow the rework by marking the function you are calling await in as async. Similar to how you need allow Overriding with inheritance.

Comment: Note that your `async` method isn't actually doing anything asynchronous. `async` only means that you're allowed to use the `await` keyword - it doesn't magically make the method run asynchronously

Comment: And the message about the return type changing is because asynchronous methods can't return non-task values directly - they can only return task types representing the asynchronous operation. (Or void, but you should avoid that.)

Comment: Why is `GetCurrentSomething` async in the first place? You should probably fit it to not use .Result, that's a code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method that is doing the await also needs to have the `async` keyword.

So this will not work:

```
public Task Hello()
{
    await _service.GetCurrentSomething(userAuthenticated);
}
```

But this will work:

```
public async Task Hello()
{
    await _service.GetCurrentSomething(userAuthenticated);
}
```

So if you are doing this call from a controller as you say, you will need to add the `async` keyword to your action method and also return a `Task<IActionResult>`. You **can** use void as well for async stuff but that is really not recommended (only for eventhandlers etc).

The **only** thing the `async` keyword gives you is that it allows you to use the `await` keyword. It will **not** make your code asynchronous unless you actually code it in that way (by using async apis, awaiting...not using .Result).

Comment: Unfortunately, as I suspected, MVC doesn't seem to like this is one of its' controllers.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It's perfectly fine having async action methods. Could you post your actual controller code?

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: Getting a 500 error hitting home page, however I believe the login portion of the home page is has to hit the dev environment which apparently looks borked at the moment.  So everything looks OK in the method?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah everything looks okay in the controller I would say. Just get rid of the ```.Result``` stuff and use await instead in your ```GetCurrentSomething``` method and u should be fine!